# To vote or not to vote? Questions that could be auto-deleted if it wasn't for their answers

Tags: discussion, off-topic, voting

**[Do scientific explanations mean that God is no longer responsible for nature?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/36548/6071)**

My question is prompted by this question. It is clearly off-topic, and of so little substance that it isn't even one that's worth keeping around even while closed.

So if it gets closed while its answers have 0 votes, then it can eventually be auto-deleted.

So how should we decide whether to vote for its answers? DJClayworth's answer is decent, but it's not amazing. And I'm sure he's said similar stuff elsewhere, so it's not like much will be lost if it does get deleted.

Answer (score 6):

I don't really see it as a big deal if it doesn't get deleted. If you think DJ deserves an up, then give him one. **I would actually admonish him to discontinue answering off-topic questions. That's why I don't even look at the answers for off-topic questions.**

Users over 10K rep can vote to delete it. Perhaps we just need more of those users doing that. Or, alternatively, you can really buckle down and get the extra 6.7K rep you need to make the vote yourself ;)

Comment: I strongly agree with the concept of not answering off-topic questions, and as an extension, not reading or voting on answers to off-topic questions.